# Cakephp 3: showing two values on form drop-down from associated table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have three tables:

BudgetRevenues - belongs to AnnualOperatingBudgets

AnnualOperatingBudgets has an Azinstitutions

In my add form for Budget Revenues the first selection is for Budget Year & Institution.

```
public function add()
    {
        $budgetRevenue = $this->BudgetRevenues->newEntity();
        $associated = [ 'RevenueTitles',  'AnnualOperatingBudgets', 'AnnualOperatingBudgets.Azinstitutions'];
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $budgetRevenue = $this->BudgetRevenues->patchEntity($budgetRevenue, $this->request->getData(), ['associated' => $associated]);
            if ($this->BudgetRevenues->save($budgetRevenue)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The budget revenue has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The budget revenue could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $annualOperatingBudgets = $this->BudgetRevenues->AnnualOperatingBudgets->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => ['budget_year', 'azinstitutions_id']]);
        $revenueTitles = $this->BudgetRevenues->RevenueTitles->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'revenue_title']);
        $this->set(compact('budgetRevenue', 'revenueTitles', 'annualOperatingBudgets', 'AnnualOperatingBudgets.Azinstitutions'));
    }
```

In my code I can call the budget year (a field in AnnualOperatingBudgets) and the azinstitution_id. But I would like it to show the name of the institution. That is in the azinstitutions table linked by the azinstitution_id in the AnnualOperatingBudgets table.

Right now the form shows 2015;1
 I would like it to show 2015 ASU

my add.ctp looks like this:

```
<div class="budgetRevenues form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
            <?= $this->Form->create($budgetRevenue) ?>
            <fieldset>
                <legend><?= __('Add Budget Revenue') ?></legend>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->control('annual_operating_budget_id', ['label' => 'Budget Year & Institution'], ['options' => $annualOperatingBudgets ]);
                    echo $this->Form->control('revenue');
                    echo $this->Form->control('revenue_title_id', ['options' => $revenueTitles]);
                ?>
            </fieldset>
            <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do with a calculated field

```
$query = $this->BudgetRevenues->AnnualOperatingBudgets->find();

$annualOperatingBudgets = $query 
->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'id', 
    'valueField' => 'full_year'
])
->select([
    'id',
    'full_year' => $query->func()->concat([
        'budget_year' => 'identifier',
        ' - ',
        'Azinstitutions.name' => 'identifier'
    ])
])
->contain(['Azinstitutions']);
```

Another solution is using a virtual property in your entity

in your `AnnualOperatingBudget` Entity create a virtual property

```
// AnnualOperatingBudget.php
public function _getFullYear()
{
    return $this->budget_year.' - '.$this->azinstitution->name;
    // You should add a check to ensure 
    // that $this->azinstitution actually exists
}

//controller
$annualOperatingBudgets = $this->BudgetRevenues->AnnualOperatingBudgets
    ->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'full_year'])
    ->contain(['Azinstitutions]);
```

Comment: Virtual Property Worked Brilliantly. Thanks so much arilia